# Fullscreen background image using ui-router

Tags: css, angularjs

I've just started with Angularjs with UI-router and I got stuck on creating the login page which I want to be fullscreen,

index.cshtml

```
<body>
    <div ng-app="myApp">
        <div ui-view></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

login.html

```
<div class="login">Login</div>
```

mystyle.css

```
body, html {
    height:100%;
}

.login {
    background-image:url(../img/bg.jpg);
    //Could change to background-color here but it doesn't matter
}
```

But this is the result:

[image]

Edit:
View in Chrome dev tools
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should inspect your page with the Chrome inspector and verify if the div that holds your app and the div that has the .login class are full page height.

In this case, you should add a class to your top div and the ui-view div and create a CSS for it.

```
.myFullscreenDiv { width: 100%; height: 100%}
.login { width: 100%; height: 100%}
```

And in your HTML

```
<body>
    <div ng-app="myApp" class="myFullscreenDiv">
        <div ui-view class="myFullscreenDiv" ></div>
    </div>
</body>
```